# Juju - Hook Failed: install

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using MaaS as juju environment. After bootstrap I set proxy's:

`juju set-env http-proxy=http://172.16.1.160` <-- My MaaS server IP

```
juju set-env no-proxy=http://172.16.1.160
```

And then deployed wordpress charm:

```
juju deploy –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress
```

Now `juju status`:

[image]

Hook failed: install, I have to do juju ssh 1 and check the logs in `/var/log/juju`.

[image]

In the `unit-wordpress-0.log` I got this:

[image]

[image]

And on the machine-1.log I got this:

[image]

The IP 172.16.1.176 - is the bootstrapped node, the juju-agent.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, a few things:

a) The syntax for no_proxy is an IP or a hostname, separated by commas, not a URL. So yours should have been just the IP. That being said, I don't think you need (or should) specify the proxy itself in there. Take a look at https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.22/howto-proxies

b) I think you are missing a port in the http-proxy variable. Or did you really install a proxy on the MAAS node on port 80?

c) That all being said, I think you hit but https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1439447. After addressing the issues in (a) and (b), and if still doesn't work, can you try with an older juju-core, like 1.20.14, or maybe 1.23beta4 where it's supposed to be fixed?

Comment: a) I did this: juju set-env no-proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,172.16.1.160, is it good now? 
b) Just now I tried juju set-env http-proxy=http://172.16.1.160:80 and it said it can't access the charm store, I didn't installed a proxy on the MAAS node on port 80, how do I do that?

Comment: You still don't have the exact right syntax for http-proxy. I edited the answer to include a link to the docs, please take a look at that. And I suggest that you bootstrap with those settings already in place in the environments.yaml file, so the bootstrap process can use the proxy too. As to how to configure a proxy, that's out of scope for this specific askubuntu question.